# Do something every X time with a cronometer

Tags: android, time, timer

I am quite noob 
I have a cronometer that begins to counter when I click a button

```
    crono = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.crono);
begin= (Button) findViewById(R.id.begin);
begin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        crono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        crono.start();

every minute do something ////////

    }
});
```

What should I do to do something every minute?
For example  1:00 ---> do something    2:00 ---> do something

Any suggestion will be apreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `OnChronometerTickListener`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    crono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    crono.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
        private long mTicks = 0;
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
            if ((mTicks / 60) == 0) { // adapt period here
                // do something
            }
            mTicks++;
        }
    });
    crono.start();
}
```

I'm not sure, how often the Cronometer ticks, my guess is every second. You may need to adapt the period, if its something else.

If it is not a constant period, you need to check the time like:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    crono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    crono.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
        private long mLastAction = 0;
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
            now = System.getCurrentMillies();
            if (now - mLastAction > 60 * 1000) {
                // do something
                mLastAction = now;
            }
        }
    });
    crono.start();
}
```

Maybe, the second one is better anyway.

Comment: Hi, with the first code it underlines in red "` Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener()"` and `" onChronometerTick"`

Comment: I just made the trivial syntax fixed. return type of the method was missing. maybe, you need to import Chronometer. Please check your IDEs error message.

Comment: I have read about   Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener()  and with a code that I have found in Stackoverflow I have done some advantatges. I have edited your answer with my new code, please check it, what should I do with the    `if (myElapsedMillis > 2)` to make it work every 10 sec?

Comment: It doesn't matter now, I think that everything is working well, it "updates" every second but its fine.  SOLVED